# How to get the points on the face to draw Delaunay triangulation

Tags: c++, opencv, face-detection, triangulation, delaunay

How can I have mouth and eyes corner points and nose central point using OpenCv like in this picture?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I think your question needs a little reformat because after reading it three times I still don't know what your question is..

Comment: @GamErix what i have to use to get mouth and eyes corner points and nose central points like on the picture !!

Comment: Use an edge detection algorithm like [Sobel operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator); then, create points on the edges. However, it will certainly be quite some work until it works reliably. I'd read scientific papers about face recognition techniques.

Comment: you can use active appearance model

Comment: I have similar problem,,just started with OpenCV for an IOS app. The blog link of marked answer is dead.. If you can provide some code or sample or links, it will be great :) Thanx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The procedure is actually like this:

`Face recognition --> face landmark --> delaunay triangulation`

The title is misleading. Delaunay is actually used after you get those points. However, I suspect your question mainly lies in how to get the face landmarks. For this you could refer to my [blog post](http://blog.solesschong.com/?p=407). It's my own implementation. However it is in Chinese that I cannot expect you to understand.

You can just search for `face landmarks` and you'll get lots of codes for that. This topic has been under exhaustive research during these decades. Also there's close source solutions on this, e.g. Visage Tech's [Visage SDK](http://www.visagetechnologies.com/download/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Active Appearance Models (AAM). [This wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_appearance_model) has links to non-commercial tools that can help you to do this with little effort.

Comment: do you have a link for a working example because  i read scientific papers about it and i understod the principe but how to implement it !!

Comment: Admittedly, most papers don't have enough detail for you to implement this kind of algorithms. Here's one:
http://code.google.com/p/aam-opencv/
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

- dlib has a landmark detector which is based on that paper:
  https://ibug.doc.ic.ac.uk/media/uploads/documents/sagonas_2016_imavis.pdf
- In c++ the code is:

```
shape_predictor pose_model;
deserialize("shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat") >> pose_model;
full_object_detection shape = pose_model(cimg,face);
```